# How do i align connected faces to axis?

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms

I have several circles, extruded from one another, so they form multiple, (parallelly dissected) cylinders, with the top and bottom of all the cylinders parallel, but not on the same axis. I want those circles to stay the size they are, but all parallel, and the center of the circles to be on the same axis, i don't really care which axis or where, but the size of the circles must remain the same.

Images show what im struggling with, without distractions of the rest of the model.

[image: First picture shows a cylinder, lying on it's side.]
[image: Second picture shows that same cylinder in orthographic from the side, and has been extruded twice, in neither case along a local or global standard x, y or z axis. they have been extruded in the z and y dimensions.]
[image: The third picture shows the mesh from picture two, in edit mode, solid, user perspective view.]
[image: Fourth image shows the mesh from 2 and 3, all circles are still paralell, but their centers are on a single axis]

Comment: Scale the circles on Y axis to 0?

Answer (score 3):

I will post 2 ways to do that.

---

**First way :**

1. Select inner circles which you are going to straighten, hit <kbd>X</kbd> and select `Edgeloops`.
2. Use loopcut tool <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and increase loopcuts to 2. These new loopcuts are your recreated circles, straightened along the line between outer circles

(Note that the angles of original circles if they were rotated aren't saved).

---

**Second way:**

(this way is a little tricky) If you do want to preserve original inner circles and not recreating them, then:

1. Select outer circles, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and select `Bridge Edge Loops`.

[image]

2. Use loopcut tool <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and make 1 loopcut on the created bridge between the outer circles. Place it roughly at the place you'd like one of the inner circles should be.
3. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and select `Cursor To Selection`. After that, while this created loopcut is still selected, hit <kbd>X</kbd> and select `Edgeloop`.

[image]

4. Select adjacent inner circle you are straightening, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and select `Selection To Cursor (Offset)`. One of your inner circles is straightened now.
5. Repeat that for another inner circle.

[image]

5. Select outer circles, hit <kbd>X</kbd> and select `Faces`. This will delete additional geometry created by `Bridge Edge Loops`.

[image]

Comment: you may be interested in this [meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/391/5113)

Comment: @Chebhou ah yeah, I was wondering how to get those keyboard shortcuts long ago. As I've got it, described way is the only one to get them placed in a post (I didn't know about <kbd> tag. Life's got easier).

Comment: thanks to  Gandalf script  makes it much easier ( also he has a theme script for the site ) look in the meta for more useful stuff